# Check condition in bash script

Tags: bash, shell

I have problem when check input from shell, can someone help me:

```
#!/bin/bash
export type=$1    
echo "$type"
if [$type=="kvm"]
then
    echo "true"
else
    echo "false"
fi
```

I expect shell will print true but the result is:

```
> bash ~/my_scripts/dssh.sh kvm
kvm
/home/xdoabui/my_scripts/dssh.sh: line 15: [kvm==kvm]: command not found
false
```

Comment: give space between `[` and `$type` and `"` and `]` like `if [ "$type" == "kvm" ]`

Comment: Great, It works now, thank a lot :)

Comment: Addendum to the first comment: `[` is a program also named `test`, and `$type`, `==`, `"kvm"`, and `]` are its arguments. Thus the spaces are mandatory.

Comment: Also, `=` is more portable than `==` in a `[ ]` (aka `test`) expression. Bash tolerates `==` as an equivalent, but not all shells (and versions of `/bin/test`) do. And [shellcheck.net](http://www.shellcheck.net) will spot a lot of these common mistakes.